# JspWriter start writing not from row 1 in excel file

Tags: java, jsp, csv, export-to-excel

i'm a newb of java programming and it is probably a simple question but I can not solve the problem:
through a javascript function I create a csv file that was send via ajax to a JSP page that write and download the csv file. 
The problem is that the data within the csv starting from row 9 and not from line 0 leaving the first nine lines empty. This is java code in JSP:

`<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");%>
<%response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=tabella.csv"); %>`

```
<logic:equal parameter="type" scope="request" value="exportCSV">
    <%
        String csv =(String)session.getAttribute("csv");
        out.print(csv.toString());
        out.flush();
    %>
</logic:equal>
```

[EDIT]

```
function exportToCSV(){
var header = '';
var csv=''; 

//get header
$table = jQuery('table');
$th = $table.find('th');
$th.each(function(){
    var text = ''+ jQuery(this).text()+ '';
    header += text + ";"; 
});
   csv += header;
   csv +="\n";
.... 
get row
}
```

how can I properly format the file?thakns in advance

Comment: Show us some more code.

Comment: Can you use `csv.toString().trim()` ?

Comment: hi at all, @The New Idiot i have tried your solution but the result is the same

Comment: @Vignesh Vino this is all server side code, if you want i can post client side code

Comment: problem solved, it is enough to add 'out.clear()' to fix the formatting